# Ajax call fails to local file in Windows phone 8 and Cordova 2.3.0rc2

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a WebApp built in PhoneGap. 
I read [this](http://www.risingj.com/archives/374) article 
So I tried to port my app to Windows Phone 8 and followed a Getting Started guide [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/12/21/how-to-develop-for-windows-phone-8-on-your-mac.aspx).

I am using Marionette.js and Cordova 2.3.0rc2. I have an ajax call here.

```
 $.ajax({
    url : urlTemp + templateId + ".html",  //This refers to a file in my local file system
    data : {},
    success : function(data) {
      App.templates[templateId] = data;
      callback.call(this, data);
    },
    error : function(err) {
      alert('ERROR LOG: Error loading Template for: ' + urlTemp + templateId + ".html");
    },
    dataType : 'text'
  });
```

Somehow this always goes in error. This works well in Android and IOS.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Is there a stack trace or can you more information on the error you get?

Comment: This is what I get in my output window:

Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID :: 46ef1840-dd2c-4531-83af-f35e68863d14
GapBrowser_Navigated :: /www/app/index.html
GapBrowser_Navigated :: /www/app/index.html#home
Log:"navigator.network.connection is deprecated. Use navigator.connection instead."
The thread 0xa84 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Log:"navigator.network.connection is deprecated. Use navigator.connection instead."
The thread 0xa88 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a local file, you may be able to use the FileReader API instead of an AJAX request to read the file data.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader

Edit: Just noticed you stated you are using 2.3.0. Removing my comments about it not yet supported in 2.2.

Comment: Ok. FileReader may provide an alternative. But whats with ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `x-wmapp0://www/` before path to your local file. In my case it helped.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in other posts in WP8, when calling ajax, path to local files must be absolute.
So you need to have "www/" in your path. Instead of calling "test.html" you would have to call "www/test.html" in order for ajax call to work.

i've come up with following solution:

1) First you need "device plugin" to be installed, in order to execute this code only on WP

2) Then we simply add "www/" before every local path, every time an ajax call is made

**this only works if all your local files, which are called are in the root "www" folder**

**if you use jquery mobile and store some of your html-files in sub folders, this code will make those files inaccessible, therefore you have to adjust it**

Following code must be executed after phonegap (and jquery mobile) is initialized:

```
if (typeof device !== "undefined") {    
    PLATFORM = device.platform.toLowerCase();
    if (PLATFORM == 'win32nt' || PLATFORM == 'wince') {         
        $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
            if (settings.url.indexOf("http") !== 0) {
                var parts = settings.url.split("/");
                settings.url = "www/" + parts[parts.length - 1];
            }           
        });         
    }
}
```